# How do i reference config element called "Random Variable" inside "Respone Assertion"?

Tags: jmeter

I need to check if "Random Variable" generated by jmeter exist on a site in its html code. I assume i need to check it using Response Assertion, however i dont know how to reference Random Variable inside Response Assertion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Help Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the SO [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should also read about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). To help people answering your question, learn how to create a [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your variable is called in [Random Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Variable):

> myVar

Then add a [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and in Patterns to check, add:

> ${myVar}

Which would end up like:

[image: Response Assertion configuration]